# How to calculate the total price of products just by increasing quantity?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have custorder models in which im taking product and price as foreign key from other models Product and price . I want to calculate the total price of product just by increasing quantity. Im just building a rest api for order creation . Please help me how to do it.

Models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):

    product_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    product = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True))

    def __str__(self):

        return str(self.product)

class Price(models.Model):

    product = models.ForeignKey('Product',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    price_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places = 5, default=0)


    def __str__(self):

        return "%s" % self.price

class CustOrder(models.Model):

    Customer_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    CustomerName = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=70,blank=True, null= True, unique= True)

    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)

    phone = PhoneField(null=False, blank=True, unique=True)

    landmark = models.PointField()

    #landmark = models.TextField(max_length=400, help_text="Enter the landmark", default='Enter landmark')

    houseno = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    #product_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=PRODUCT_CHOICES,default='Boneless chicken')

    # product_id = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='custorder_productid')

    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True,related_name='pricetag')

    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    # price_id = models.ForeignKey(Price)

    price = models.ForeignKey(Price, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,related_name='pricetag')

    #price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places=5, default=48.9)

    pay_method = models.CharField(max_length=200,choices=PAYMENT_CHOICES, default='RAZOR PAY')

    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    area = models.ForeignKey(Area, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
 def __str__(self):

        return self.CustomerName
```

Comment: You models seem to have wrong relations: You have `Product` and `Price` as FK in `CustOrder` but `Price` also have `Product` as FK. 
I believe you need to have a `Product` model with a single product not Array, that have `price` field. Then you would need a model like `OrderProduct` where you indicate `product` `order` and `quantity`.

Comment: Can't I calculate total with this same model

Comment: and you dont need to create a separate table for it you should simply keep it a `FloatField`

Comment: Please tell me how to calculate the price in this model as im new to django

Comment: It's not clear what the price would even be in this model. If someone wants to look up the price of an order, should they use the price that was saved to CustOrder or the price that they can get from looking at the price of the product that is part of the order. I agree with the first comment that there is something wrong with this model. If this is the model that you have to use then you need to look at how data gets saved when an order is made, and then use that to figure out where you can actually look up the right price.